# Boot error after upgrading to W10, tried to fix it with a W7 disc, think I screwed up

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10

I recently upgraded my father's laptop from Windows 7 to Windows 10. A few days later he tells me Windows won't start.

I get a "The Windows Boot Configuration Data file is missing required information" screen.

Since I only had the original Windows 7 installation disc, I tried to repair the boot with it. Did the usual bootrec commands (fixboot, fixmbr, rebuildbcd) and got the same error again. Booted from the disc again and it listed both Windows 10 and Windows 7 as available systems, and bootrec /rebuildbcd now returns 0 available operating systems.

How can I fix this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reinstalling windows 10, you should be able to create a installation disk by using the Media creation tool directly from the windows website [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). If you simply reinstall over it you shouldn't lose any data on your computer. I hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't know such tool existed! I should be able to repair the installation with that. Thanks.